# gcc detect duplicate symbols/functions in static libraries

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way we can get gcc to detect a duplicate symbol in static libraries vs the main code (Or another static library ?)

Here's the situation:

main.c erroneously contained a function definition, e.g. with the signature `uint foohash(const char*)`

foo.c also contains a function definition with the signature `uint foohash(const char*)`

foo.c and other source files are compiled to a static util library, which the main program links in, i.e. something like:

```
 gcc -o main main.o util.o -L ./libs -lfooutils
```

So, now main.o and libs/libfooutils.a both contain a foohash function. Presumably the linker found that symbol in main.o and doesn't bother looking for it elsewhere.

Is there any way we can get gcc to detect such a situation ?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg , the "Presumably" was intended to convey the reason for gcc picking the symbol up from main.o, I already know which of the two is being linked in. But anyway, that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed as Simon Richter stated, `--whole-archive` option can be useful. Try to change your command-line to:

```sh
 gcc -o main main.o util.o -L ./libs -Wl,--whole-archive -lfooutils -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

and you'll see a multiple definition error.

Comment: Is there an equivalent w/ clang? ld: unknown option: --whole-archive (Apple LLVM version 8.1.0)

Comment: @moof2k Try `-all_load`

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` calls the `ld` program for linking.  The relevant `ld` options are:

```
--no-define-common
--traditional-format
--warn-common
```

See the man page for `ld`.  These should be what you need to experiment with to get the warnings sought.

Comment: In line with this answer, I added `-Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--fatal-warnings` to my GCC arguments. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

GCC does not actually do anything with libraries. It is the task of `ld`, the linker (called automatically by GCC) to pull in symbols from libraries, and that's really a fairly dumb tool.

The linker has lots of complex jiggery pokery for combining different types of data from different sources, and supporting different file formats, and all the evil little details of binary executables, but in the end, all it really does is look for undefined symbols and find the definitions.

What you can do is a link trace (pass `-t` to gcc) to see what comes from where. Or else run `nm` on all the object files and libraries in your system, and write a script to detect duplicates.