# How to detect C symbol conflicts in R

Tags: c, r, libcurl

The curl R package was giving misterious [segfaults](http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_curl.html) on Solaris (both GCC and Solaris Studio build of R). Through trial and error I found that the solution was to rename an internal C function called `fetch` to something different and now everything works fine.

I suppose there must have been some kind of naming conflict, but I don't understand why the compiler did not warn me. Where can I find if a function has been defined elsewhere? How can I detect/prevent/debug such problems in the future?

Comment: The first rule of R tests on Solaris is to not talk about R tests on Solaris.

Comment: And by the way, C++ has namespaces :)

Comment: There are some [options explored here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093891/gcc-detect-duplicate-symbols-functions-in-static-libraries) related to `ld` (but who knows what is available / usable on Solaris.