# xcode ld detect duplicate symbol in static libraries

Tags: xcode, clang, ld, darwin

This question has been asked previously for [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093891/gcc-detect-duplicate-symbols-functions-in-static-libraries), but Darwin's ld (clang?) appears to handle this differently.

Say I have a `main()` function defined in two files, main1.cc and main2.cc. If I attempt to compile these both together I'll get (the desired) duplicate symbol error:

```
$ g++ -o main1.o -c main1.cc
$ g++ -o main2.o -c main2.cc
$ g++ -o main main1.o main2.o
duplicate symbol _main in:
    main1.o
    main2.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But if I instead stick one of these into a static library, when I go to link the application I won't get an error:

```
$ ar rcs libmain1.a main1.o
$ g++ -o main libmain1.a main2.o
(no error)
```

With gcc you can wrap the lib with `--whole-archive` and then gcc's ld will produce an error. This option is not available with the ld that ships w/ xcode.

Is it possible to get ld to print an error?

Comment: `main()` is a global function, it is the entry point of a program. Every process is a instance of program.

If you just link two object file then generate final executable program, it must only have one `main()` function.

If you link a static library, the entry point is the `main()` function in `main2.o`. Linker will copy-paste any extern code that `main2.o` need but 
actually exist in `libmain1.a`. The `main()` function in `libmain1.a` will not exist in finally program `main`. So that's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure you know that you're not supposed to put an object file 
containing a `main` function in a static library. In case any of our readers
doesn't: A library is for containing  functions that may be reused by many programs.
A program can contain only one  `main` function, and the likelihood
is negligible that the `main` function of program will be reusable as the `main`
function of another. So `main` functions don't go in libraries. (There are a few odd exceptions to this rule).

On then to the problem you're worried about. For simplicity,
I'll exclude linkage of shared/dynamic libraries from consideration in the rest of this.

Your linker detects a duplicate symbol error (a.k.a. multiple definition error) 
in the linkage when the competing definitions are in different input object files
but doesn't detect it when one definition is an input object file and the other 
is in an input static library. In that scenario, the GNU linker *can* detect 
the multiply defined symbol if it is passed the `--whole-archive` option before 
the static library. But your linker, the [Darwin Mach-O linker](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/ld.1.html), 
doesn't have that option.

Note that while your linker doesn't support `--whole-archive`, it has an
equivalent option `-all_load`. But don't run away with that, because the worry is groundless anyhow. For both linkers:

- There really *is* a multiple definition error in the linkage in the [`foo.o` ...
  `bar.o`] case.
- There really is *not* a multiple definition error in the linkage in the [`foo.o` ... `libbar.a`] case.

And in addition for the GNU linker:

- There really *is* a multiple definition error in the linkage in the
  [`foo.o` ... `--whole-archive libbar.a`] case.

In no case does either linker allow multiple definitions of a symbol to
get into your program undetected and arbitrarily use one of them.

**What's the difference between linking `foo.o` and linking `libfoo.o`?**

The linker will only add *object files* to your program.
More precisely, when it meets an input file `foo.o`, it adds to your program
all the symbol references and symbol definitions from `foo.o`. (For starters
at least: it may finally discard unused definitions if you've requested that,
and if it can do so without collaterally discarding any used ones).

A static library is just a bag of object files. When the linker meets an input file
`libfoo.a`, by default it won't add *any* of the object files in the bag to
your program.

It will only inspect the contents of the bag *if it has to, at that point in the linkage*.

It will *have to* inspect the contents of the bag if it has already added
some symbol references to your program that don't have definitions. Those
*unresolved symbols* might be defined in some of the object files in the bag.

If it has to look in the bag, then it will inspect the object files to
see if any of them contain definitions of unresolved symbols already in the
program. If there are any such object files then it will add them to the program and consider afresh whether it needs to keep looking in the bag. It stops looking in the bag when it finds no more object files in it that the program needs or has found definitions for all symbols referenced by the program, whichever comes first.

If any object files in the bag are needed, this adds at least one more symbol 
definition to your program, and possibly more unresolved symbols. Then the linker carries on.
Once it has met `libfoo.a` and considered which, if any, object files in that bag it needs for your program,
it won't consider it again, unless it meets it *again*, later in the linkage
sequence.

**So...**

*Case 1*. The input files contain [`foo.o` ... `bar.o`]. Both `foo.o` and `bar.o`
define symbol `A`. Both object files must be linked, so both definitions of `A` must 
be added to the program and that is a multiple definition error. Both linkers detect it.

*Case 2* The input files contain [`foo.o` ... `libbar.a`].

- `libbar.a` contains object files `a.o` and `b.o`.
- `foo.o` defines symbol `A` and references, but does not define, symbol `B`.
- `a.o` also defines `A` but does not define `B`, and defines no other symbols
  that are referenced by `foo.o`.
- `b.o` defines symbol `B`.

Then:-

- At `foo.o`, the object file must be linked. The linker adds the 
  definition of `A` and an unresolved reference to `B` to the program.
- At `libbar.a`, the linker needs a definition for unresolved reference `B` so it looks in the bag.
- `a.o` does not define `B` or any other unresolved symbol. It is not linked. The second definition of `A` is not added.
- `b.o` defines `B`, so it is linked. The definition of `B` is added to the program.
- The linker carries on.

No two object files that both define `A` are needed in the program. There is no
multiple definition error.

*Case 3* The input files contain [`foo.o` ... `libbar.a`].

- `libbar.a` contains object files `a.o` and `b.o`.
- `foo.o` defines symbol `A`. It references but does not define, symbols `B` and `C`.
- `a.o` also defines `A` and it defines `B`, and defines no other symbols
  that are referenced by `foo.o`.
- `b.o` defines symbol `C`.

Then:-

- At `foo.o`, the object file is linked. The linker adds to the program the definition of `A` and a  unresolved references to `B` and `C`.
- At `libbar.a`, the linker needs definitions for unresolved references`B` 
  and `C` so it looks in the bag.
- `a.o` does not define `C`. But it does define `B`. So `a.o` is linked. That adds the required definition of `B`, plus the not-required, *surplus* definition of `A`.

That is a multiple definition error. Both linkers detect it. Linkage ends.

There *is* a multiple definition error if and only if two definitions
of some symbol are contained in object files *that are linked in the program*. Object files from a static library are linked only to provide definitions of symbols that the program references. If there is
a multiple definition error, then both linkers detect it.

**So why does the GNU linker option `--whole-archive` give different outcomes?**

Suppose that `libbar.a` contains `a.o` and `b.o`. Then:

```
foo.o --whole-archive -lbar
```

tells the linker to link all the object files in `libbar.a` whether
they are *needed* or not. So this fragment of the linkage command is simply equivalent
to:

```
foo.o a.o b.o
```

Thus in *case 2* above, the addition of `--whole-archive` is a way of
*creating* a multiple definition error where there is *none* without it. Not
a way of *detecting* a multiple definition error that was not detected without
it.

And if `--whole-archive` is mistakenly is used as a way "detecting" fictitious
multiple definition errors, then in those cases where the linkage nevertheless
succeeds, it is also a way of *adding an unlimited amount of redundant code
to the program*. The same goes for the `-all_load` option of the Mach-O linker.

**Not satisfied?**

Even when all that is clear, maybe you still hanker for some way to make it
an error when an input object file in your linkage defines a symbol that
is also defined in another object file that is not needed by the linkage but
happens to be contained in some input static library.

Well, that might be a situation that you want to know about, but it just
isn't any kind of *linkage error*, multiple-definition or otherwise. The *purpose*
of static libraries in linkage is to provide default definitions of symbols
that you don't define in the input object files. Provide your own definition
in an object file and the libary default is ignored.

If you don't want linkage to work like that - the way it is intended to work - 
but:-

- You still want to use a static library
- You don't want any definition from an input object file ever to prevail over 
  one that's in a member of the static library
- You don't want to link any redundant object files.

then the simplest solution (though not necessarily the least time-consuming at build time)
is this:

In your project build extract all the members of the static library as a
prerequisite of the link step in a manner that also gives you the list of
their names, e.g.:

```
$ LIBFOOBAR_OBJS=`ar xv libfoobar.a | sed 's/x - //'g`
$ echo $LIBFOOBAR_OBJS
foo.o bar.o
```

(But extract them someplace where they cannot clobber any object files you build). Then, again before the link step, run a preliminary throw-away
linkage in which `$LIBFOOBAR_OBJS` replaces `libfoobar.a`. E.g
instead of

```
cc -o prog x.o y.o z.o ... -lfoobar ...
```

run

```
cc -o deleteme x.o y.o z.o ... $LIBFOOBAR_OBJS ...
```

If the preliminary linkage fails - with a multiple definition error or
anything else - then stop there. Otherwise go ahead with the real linkage.
You won't link any redundant object files in `prog`. The price is performing
a linkage of `deleteme` that is redundant unless it fails with a multiple
definition error<sup>1</sup>

In professional practice, nobody runs builds like that to head off the
remote possibility that a programmer has defined a function in
one of `x.o y.o z.o` that knocks out a function defined in a member of
`libfoobar.a` *without meaning to*. Competence and code-review are
counted on to avoid that, in the same way they are counted on to avoid
a programmer defining a function in `x.o y.o z.o` to do anything that
should be be done using library resources.

---

[1] Rather than extracting all the object files from the static
library for use in the throw-away linkage, you might consider a
throwaway linkage using `--whole-archive`, with the GNU linker,
or `-all_load`, with the Mach-O linker. But there are potential pitfalls with
this approach I won't delve into here.