# How to prevent duplicate symbols in static library?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, ld

Is there a way to create a warning or error if creating a static library with duplicate symbols? Given the example project below, I can create an error during link time by including the `-all_load` option, but otherwise cannot seem to avoid `ld` silently selecting the first symbol without any warning.

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(hello)

set(SOURCE_FILES hello1.cpp hello2.cpp hello.h)
add_library(hellolib ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(hellobin main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hellobin hellolib)
```

#### hello.h

```
#pragma once

void hello();
```

#### hello1.cpp

```
#include "hello.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

#### hello2.cpp

```
#include "hello.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
  std::cout << "Goodbye, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
  hello();
}
```

As mentioned above, I can generate an issue if I add the all_load option to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -all_load")
```

Is there some way to generate this instead at the static library generation step?

#### Update

I am able to cause CMake to throw an error if I perform the following check with `nm` and add a custom command to my `CMakeLists.txt` (though it still seems hacky):

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
add_custom_command(TARGET hellolib POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/check_build.sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libhellolib.a)
```

#### check_build.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ];
then
    echo "err: usage ./check_build.sh <lib file>"
    exit 1
fi

MAX_SYM=`nm $1 | perl -ne 'print if / T .+$/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ "$MAX_SYM" -ne "1" ]
then
    echo "Saw duplicate symbol."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why would one want to do that? That's what name spaces are for.

Comment: @Kaveh I think the code posted is just by way of illustration.  I imagine the OP wants to guard against mistakes.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSanders, that's exactly what I'm asking for

Comment: it really helps to read the question. sorry for that. i don't think that this is possible with functions. macros would be detectable during compilation but functions, as far as i know not. was just now playing with `cppcheck` and then realised that it cannot be done by individual compilation units.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a good way of coding. If you really need to use the same name, you can `inline` the function. But really consider doing it properly with namespaces.

Putting hello() in a distinct namespace would prevent accidental double implementation. I don't think that what you want to do is possible with individual compilation units, which only see parts of code.

Anyway my 2 cents on this.

Comment: Thanks @Kaveh, the question I'm asking is about generating errors when building static libraries (which is why the example project is structured that way)

Answer (score 0):

I think that role is not an responsibility of gcc. That is responsibility of ld. so this is makes sense.

[gcc detect duplicate symbols/functions in static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093891/gcc-detect-duplicate-symbols-functions-in-static-libraries)

Comment: Thanks @Yoseob, updated to clarify that I can generate the error during link time but want to generate an error during the static library building phase

Comment: I doubt that is possible.  The program that builds the library (ar) just basically stitches object files together.  Maybe the thing to do is to link the library with a simple test program after building it to see if that link produces any warnings.  Sounds simple enough.

Comment: I can also run `nm` to catch duplicate symbols in the file. I could just add a simple check with `nm` wherever I build a library, but that seems hacky

Comment: `nm libhellolib.a | perl -ne 'print if / T .+$/' | sort  | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @Akiva You should post that as an answer to you own question, it's hard to see buried in the comments like this and it might earn you some rep.  If you @ me it certain will.

Comment: Thanks @Paul I’m not sure how best to add but have updated the original post with an “update” that hopefully illustrates my solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Akiva The usual thing is to answer your own question but that's fine, voted up.